# Directly passing html code into WebKit

Tags: cocoa, webkit

How do I pass HTML code contained in a `NSString` directly into WebKit. I'm looking for something similar to:

```
[aNSTextField setString:@"foo"];
```

Would it be as simple as something like that? Or would I have to resort to something like saving the text to a file and then accessing it with a `file://` url?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a `WebView`:

```
[[myWebView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:myHTMLString baseURL:myBaseURL];
```